# php Changing case/punctuation in concatenated sentences

Tags: php, arrays

The code below produced some random 'poetry' from the `$sentences` array. About half of the sentences end with a semicolon; where that is the case, I would like to change the first letter of the following concatenated sentence to lowercase. ALSO if the last punctuation mark in the poem is a semicolon, I'd like to change that to a period.

Thanks for any code or suggestions you can offer!

```
<?php 

$sentences = array (
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet; ",
"Consectetur adipisicing elit; ",
"Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua; ",
"Ut enim ad minim veniam; ",
"Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat; ",
"Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate; ",
"Velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur; ",
"Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident; ",
"Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum; ",
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium; ",
"Totam rem aperiam; ",
"Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo; ",
"Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit. ",
"Sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. ",
"Neque porro quisquam est. ",
"Qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet. ",
"Consectetur, adipisci velit. ",
"Sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. ",
"Ut enim ad minima veniam. ",
"Quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam. ",
"Nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? ",
"Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur. ",
"Vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? ",
);

$lastlen = null;
while ($lastlen == null OR ($wrapsize - $lastlen) > ($wrapsize / 10) /* OR $leftover > 0 */ )
{ 
    $pick = rand(7,14);
    shuffle ($sentences);
    $key = 0;
    $fullstring = '';
    while ($key < $pick) 
        { $fullstring .= $sentences[$key];
            $key++; } 

    $wrapsize = rand (20, 70);
    $poemtext = wordwrap($fullstring, $wrapsize, "\n");
    $lines = explode ("\n", $poemtext);
    $count = count($lines);

    $lastkey = $count - 1 ; $lastline = $lines[$lastkey]; 
    $lastlen = strlen($lastline);
    $stanza_size = rand(2,4);
    $leftover = $count % $stanza_size;

    $key = 0; $i = 1;       
    $final = '';
    while ($key < $count) {
        if($i > 0 && $i % $stanza_size == 0) 
        {
        $final .= $lines[$key]."<br><br>";
        $key++; $i++;
        }
        else {
        $final .= $lines[$key]."<br>";
        $key++; $i++;
        }
    } 
}

echo $final;

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
// Boolean to tell us when to make lowercase
$makeLowerCase = false;
while ($key < $pick) 
{
    // Grab the random sentence from the array
    $randomPick = $sentences[$key];

    // If we need to make lowercase the first letter, then do so now
    if($makeLowerCase)
    {
        $randomPick = lcfirst($randomPick);
    }

    // If the end of the random sentence contains a semi-colon, then
    // tell the loop to capitalize the next sentence
    $posSC = strpos($randomPick, ";");
    if($posSC !== false)
    {
        $makeLowerCase = true;
    }

    $fullstring .= $randomPick;
    $key++;
} 

// Replace the final character with a period if it's a semi-colon
$lastChar = substr($fullstring, -1);
if(lastChar == ";")
{
    $finalPoem = substr($fullstring, 0, -1) . ".";
}
```

Comment: Thank you MasterKale! That did the trick. I made a few slight changes:
`else {$makelowercase = false}` keeps the loop from lowercasing all the sentences. Also, I used `$lastChar = substr($randomPick, -2,1)` instead of `$posSC = strpos($randomPick, ";")` ... this allows a semicolon *within* a sentence from the array (rather than just at the end) without lowercasing the following sentence.